# How is the second touch of “DEAF” written in Stokoe notation?

Tags: sign-languages, notation

I am trying to understand Stokoe notation, but I am not clear how to specify the location of a second contact, such as in the [ASL sign “DEAF”](https://media.spreadthesign.com/video/mp4/13/4038.mp4).

Presumably the general representation of that sign should be something like

ȜG<sup>xvŋx</sup>

but I would assume there would be a way to specify “∪” as the location of the second “×”.